# "mysql illegal mix of collations for operation '<=' " error in magento admin section

Tags: mysql, magento, collation

I transferred my `magento` website including its `Mysql` database to a new hosting. My `magento` website is up and running but when I try to login into the admin section, the error

> mysql illegal mix of collations for operation '<='"`

is shown.

What is the problem here ?

Comment: Do you compare **strings** with `<=`?

Comment: Let's see the SQL statement !

Comment: excuse me! but i did not write the SQL statements myself! I've just transferred the files and imported the database from one hosting to another and edited the app/etc/local.xml file; i don't know about php & mysql...